# Cannot pass data from Runnable class to Service class

Tags: java, android

I want to pass data to my service class. My model created with implements Serializable.

Runnable class

```
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
Intent serviceIntent = new Intent(mContext,InitLocationsOnStartup.class);
List<StationViewModel> stationList = new ArrayList<StationViewModel>();
......
....
bundle.putSerializable("stations",stationList); //Wrong 2nd argument type. Found: 'java.util.List<StationViewModel>', required: 'java.io.Serializable'
```

or

```
  serviceIntent.putExtra("stations",stationList);//Cannot resolve method 'putExtra(java.lang.String, java.util.List<StationViewModel>
```

How do i pass the data?

Comment: Just make `StationViewModel` implement `Serializable` .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to **`serialize`** your `stationList` `List`

```
bundle.putSerializable("stations", (Serializable) stationList);
```

> **OR**

`implements` **Serializable** to your **`StationViewModel`** class like this

**`public class StationViewModel implements Serializable`**

Answer (score 1):

try to serialize your data

```
bundle.putSerializable("stations", (Serializable) stationList);
```

or

```
Intent serviceIntent = new Intent(YourActivity.this, bgservice.class);
serviceIntent.putExtra("stations", (Serializable) stationList);
this.startService(serviceIntent);
```